# Keen in or keen

Tags: grammar

I am interested to know the usage of the word keen in a phrase. Do we use the word in or on after the word keen in a sentence? For example, keen on advertising.

Comment: Which part of the [definition](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/keen_1) makes you think that keen _in_ would be correct?

Comment: I don't think anybody is keen in advertising. Should it be keen on advertising?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Keen on" means that you like something or would like to do something. "Keen in" means that something is literally or figuratively sharp.

I'm **keen on** going for Korean food at lunch.

She's **keen in** intelligence.